# How do I get this SetInterval to stop on hover off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, slideshow, setinterval

I have a stack of images I'm bringing in from YouTube, and I want the top image to fade out on hover and then start a rotating slideshow of the next 3 images. I've almost got it working but I'm having an issue with getting the SetInterval to stop when I hover off of the thumbnail.

```
thumbRotate: function(){} //This is up in the main object

//hover state over thumbs and slideshow animation       
$('#youtube-widget ul a').hover(
    // hover-in
    function(){
        $this = $(this);

        $(this).children('.title-overlay').children('h5, img, span').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '0'}, 200, function() {
            $.Modules.VideoWidget.thumbRotate = setInterval(function() { 
                var topImage = $this.children('img:first');
                topImage.stop(true, true).fadeOut(500).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn(500).end().appendTo($this);
            }, 2000);
        });
    //hover-out 
    }, function() {
        clearInterval($.Modules.VideoWidget.thumbRotate);
        $(this).children('.title-overlay').children('h5, img, span').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '1'}, 200);
    }
);
```

edit: I noticed that hovering over the thumbnail seems to be increasing animation exponentially. For some reason the animations seem to be stacking up on themselves, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: Seems like that should work, but clearing the interval doesn't stop already queued animations.

Comment: @adeneo he's calling stop right after the clearInterval

Comment: Maybe it's that variable? I mean it should work, but that's all I can think of. Maybe try console.log the value of the interval value or just use a standard var right above the hover() call and use it for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem - .hover() and .mouseover()...
Both of these functions perform an action not only when the cursor enters the element but also every time the mouse moves a single pixel within the element. In other words those 2 functions are great for simpler interactions, but it is necessary to use .mouseenter() and mouseleave() to setup interval functions otherwise you end up setting a new interval every time the cursor moves within the element (which can be a lot).

new fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mb8/2/
new code -

```
//thumb rotate animation on hover
function startRotate($this) {
    $.Modules.VideoWidget.thumbRotate = setInterval ( function() { 
        topImage = $this.children('img').filter(":first");
        topImage.animate({opacity: '0'}, 500).next().animate({opacity: '1'}, 500).end().appendTo($this);                                        
    }, 800);
}
function stopRotate() {
    clearInterval($.Modules.VideoWidget.thumbRotate);
}

$("#youtube-widget ul a").mouseenter(function() {               
    $this = $(this);
    startRotate($this);                     
}).mouseleave(function() {              
    stopRotate();               
});

//hover state over thumbs and slideshow animation       
$('#youtube-widget ul a').hover( function(){
    $this.children('.title-overlay').children('h5, img, span').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function() {
    });
//hover-out 
}, function() {
    $this.children('.title-overlay').children('h5, img, span').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '1'}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your variable name I think. It's working here:

I just added this and used it in both intervals

```
var hoverInterval;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mb8/

Comment: Yours doesn't stop animating either. Mouse in and out of it a few times, it just needs to build up.

Comment: hmm I see. Maybe add in a clear interval before the set. Maybe it's setting two and then overriding the variable before it can clear? Looks like their are two intervals and that should prevent it.

if(hoverInterval) clearInterval(hoverInterval);